# Users getting redirected to ios app when deep linking is turned off

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-page, facebook-ios-sdk

Deep linking is turned off for our app

[image: deep linking turned off]

But when ios users click a link we posted on our facebook page to our page app (https://apps.facebook.com/nakedwines/), they are redirected to the ios app instead of our competition page.

If an ios user enters the link manually into their browser, this works.

Is this a bug or is there something not set up right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a completely new facebook app for the competition page. This got round all of the issues. Facebook doesn't seem to play well if you have both a page app and ios/android apps under the same application.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that when mobile users try to access your app they're brought to the app store (when the app isn't installed) ? That's expected, if the app was installed it would be opened directly.

If you don't have an IOS app, remove the IOS details from the app settings and they'll be brought to your mobile web URL instead.

The Deep linking setting allows users who click posts from your app to be brought into the app with sufficient context to allow your app to display a specific piece of content. 
i.e links to your app's content are passed through to the native app with the full URL, and your app can open that content directly.

For example, clicking a link to a spotify song on iOS opens the spotify app and plays that song, without deep linking it just opens spotify with no context.

Comment: This is not the issue.

We have both a facebook app (a competition) and an ios (and android) app. When an ios user clicks on a link to the competition (should go to the competition facebook app), they are redirected to the ios app.

This is not the behaviour we were expecting. The facebook app is completely different to the ios app. How can we get around this issue?

Comment: Do the apps use the same base domain? (i.e could a post to the 'wrong' app look the same as a post to the 'right' app when you compare the URLs?)

Comment: On our facebook page, we posted a link to the competition app (https://apps.facebook.com/nakedwines/). On web browsers and android phones this links through to our competition facebook app. On ios phones our ios app opens up instead. The facebook app, ios app and android app are all configured in the same account on developers.facebook.com

Comment: Are you sure the app settings for the app don't list the app store ID / bundle ID, etc of the ios app? that's the most likely reason users would be brought there